# Initializing pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I see two option to assign a pointer

1.

```
int p=5;
int *r=&p
```

2.

```
int p
int *r;
r=&p;
```

Why do they use in 1 with asterisk
and in two without?

Comment: 1st one is initialization. 2nd one is assignment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read this:

```
int *r [...]
```

as:

```
(int *) r [...]
```

The type of `r` is `int *`. If you look at it that way, you'll see that both versions are identical.

Comment: oh I think that im understand one more question
what will happend i I will do this

int p;

int *r;
*r=&p;
?

Comment: `r` is of type `int*`, so `*r` is of type `int`. You should get a warning from your compiler (if not, please make sure you've turned warnings on). `*r = &p` tries to assign a pointer (`&p`) to an int (`*r`). That's not portable/safe.

Answer (score 3):

The two alternatives are actually the same. The first is just less text.

The asterisk, when used in a declaration like `int *r`, is what tells the compiler that the variable `r` *is* a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Case 2: `int *r` is a declaration of an uninitialized pointer to `int`; `r = &p` is an assignment which sets the value to the pointer.

Case 1: `int *r=&p` is a declaration of a pointer to `int` which is initialized with the address of `p`.

Answer (score 0):

The second is exactly the same. The first example **declares** the variable and **assigns value** too in one go. The **declaration** part needs the `*`, as that specifies that this variable will store a pointer to an int value. The **value assignment** part doesn't need this kind of thing, since the variable `r` is already **declared** to be a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

because in `1. int *r=&p` is declaration.

and in `2. r=&p` is not in declaration.

asterix (*) means data type of pointer.

For more information, you can read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)